# Wait for a specific time in thread, use WaitForSingleObject?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, timer

I need to wait some time in one of my threads, I started to think about `WaitForSingleObject` but it needs handles to wait on, although it can take a timeout input;

Another resolution may use `SetTimer` but it seems that it will create `WM_TIMER` message but I don't have change to catch that message since I am in a thread, so is there something I can use here ? can I use `Sleep`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include which platform and language you're using. I *suspect* it's C++ and Win32, but you should be explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper method strongly depends on what you mean with `to wait some time`. The [Sleep function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [WaitForSingleObject function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are basically of the same accuracy.
Depending on the underlaying hardware and the version of the OS minimum delays achievable are in the range of 0 .. 1 .. 20ms. If you desire to just wait for seconds or 10th of seconds these two functions are the right choice.

Waiting for shorter periods in time i.e. in the millisecond range needs more detailed investigation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11760590/1504523) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11470617/1504523) answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

WM_TIMER is not very reliable. It's a low priority windows message and it isn't sent if the user is resizing the window (for example).

I would say "Sleep" is the best option, but in the past I have used WaitForSingleObject because it allows me to pass in a handle to Cancel the wait operation if I need to. Depends on your design.

Comment: I didn't have handle here, I only want to wait for one period.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make the thread wait for a fixed amount of time, use `Sleep()` for that.  But if you want the wait to be interruptable by some external operation, you have to wait on something, whether that be a timer (see `SetTimer()` and `Get/PeekMessage()`), an event (see `CreateEvent()` and `WaitForSingleObject()`), a message in the thread's queue (see `PostThreadMessage()` and `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`), an I/O Completion Port callback (see `PostQueuedCompletionStatus()` and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`),  etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block a thread and wait until a specific time, you can use the `CreateWaitableTimer()` function, and then use `WaitForSingleObject()` on the timer handle.

This function can also wait for a specific period and with `WaitForMultipleObjects()` will let you block until the timer interval AND other objects at the same time.